# While loop never meets condition

Tags: python

So, for context I am trying to write a script that checks a text input fulfils all of the necessary requirements for a username.

However, the section I wrote to repeat the function if the conditions are not met always repeats after the first attempt even if the conditions are met. The first attempt works as intended.

This is the section that uses a list of conditions not met to establish whether or not to repeat the function, however even when the username is correct it repeats if after the first attempt.

```
   if error_stack != []:
      repeat = True
    else:
      repeat = False
    return repeat

  repeat = username_input(input("Please enter a username with only numbers and letters, which is above 2 characters and below 15 characters. If the username is taken you will be asked to pick a new one. \n|:"))
  print(repeat) #please help its always true.....

  while repeat == True:
    repeat = username_input(input("Please enter a username with only numbers and letters, which is above 2 characters and below 15 characters. If the username is taken you will be asked to pick a new one. \n|:"))
    print(repeat) #please help its always true.....

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

In this screenshot I input 1 username which should result in the control var being set to True and the loop repeating, then I input 1 username which should result in the control var being set to False and the loop not repeating.

[2 inputs 1 works other doesnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZrOK.png)

In this screenshot I input 1 user name which should result in the control var being set to False and the loop not repeating. It then works as intended.

[1 input works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m09c.png)

Can someone please explain to me why the condition only functions as it should (as far as I'm aware it should check if the condition is met every time the loop ends after the first time) the first time, then after refuses to exit?

Edit: Full code of section

```
import os

STANDARD_CHARS = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ")
ERROR_DICT = {
  "NonStandardCharacterError":"Your username should only have letters and numbers in it, please pick another.",
  "CurrentUserError":"Your username has already been taken, please pick another.",
  "LengthError":"Your username should be more than 2 characters in length, and fewer than 15 characters in length, please pick another.",
  }

def main():
  printed_errors = []
  error_stack = []
  current_users = []

  def username_input(word_input):

    for char in list(word_input.lower()):
      if char not in STANDARD_CHARS:
        error_stack.append("NonStandardCharacterError")
    if word_input.lower() in current_users:
      error_stack.append("CurrentUserError")
    if len(word_input) > 15 or len(word_input) < 3:
      error_stack.append("LengthError")
    for error in error_stack:
      try:
        if error not in printed_errors:
          print(ERROR_DICT[error])
          printed_errors.append(error)
      except KeyError:
        print("Your username has thrown an unknown error , please try again later or pick another username.")
    if error_stack != []:
      repeat = True
    else:
      repeat = False
    return repeat

  repeat = username_input(input("Please enter a username with only numbers and letters, which is above 2 characters and below 15 characters. If the username is taken you will be asked to pick a new one. \n|:"))
  print(repeat)

  while repeat == True:
    repeat = username_input(input("Please enter a username with only numbers and letters, which is above 2 characters and below 15 characters. If the username is taken you will be asked to pick a new one. \n|:"))
    print(repeat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your `username_input` function. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added all of my code which should be reproducible

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Do you mean the code as it is written? Or is it somewhere in the questions formatting, Please include some context and/or line no.

Comment: fix indentation in code in question. Indentations are very important in Python so we have to see your real indentations. Indentations can change how code works so we can see wrong result or not see your problem when we run you code.

Comment: @BramVanroy, while the indentation of the full code is a bit unusual, it's syntactically valid and the program does run as-is. You're allowed to define one function inside another, although it's not very commonly done.

Comment: @furas that is the correct indentation as proven by Kevin who managed to reproduce what happened to me and trace the problem.

Comment: it was only answer for your question where to fix code - in question or in code when you write. The answer is: fix indentations in question if it different then in your code. Many people doesn't care of indentations in question and then it makes problem to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `error_stack` to `[]` in `main`, and append to it in username_input. But after its initial creation, you never reset it back to the empty list. So `error_stack` grows and grows, retaining old errors even when the user enters valid input.

Try creating `error_stack` inside `username_input` instead of inside `main`. Then it will be set to the empty list for every new user input prompt.

```
def main():
  printed_errors = []
  current_users = []

  def username_input(word_input):
    error_stack = []
    for char in list(word_input.lower()):
      #...
```

If, for some reason, it is necessary to keep `error_stack` in the higher scope, you can instead clear it with the `clear` method.

```
def main():
  printed_errors = []
  error_stack = []
  current_users = []

  def username_input(word_input):
    error_stack.clear()
    for char in list(word_input.lower()):
      #...
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem, apologies for such a stupid mistake, I merely forgot to put the variable back within the scope of the function  because I didn't originally use main, rather putting the variable in the global scope as I intended to just test an idea I was working on. I will accept your answer when it allows me to and thank your for answering concisely and quickly.